# system.formatexception string was not recognized as a valid datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get a FormatException with the message "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." on the following line of code:

```
SqlCommand scmd1 = new SqlCommand("select count(*) Kount  from chequerequests1 where requestdate between '" + DateTime.ParseExact(txtFromDate.Text, "dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " 00:00:00.000' and '" + DateTime.ParseExact(txtToDate.Text, "dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " 23:59:59.999' group by chequebookstatus", sc);
```

- DateFormat is "dd/MM/yyyy"
- The current culture is en-GB
- I've tried various variants of DateTimeStyles but to no effect.

Please suggest what is wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Whats the value you're getting from `txtFromDate.Text`?

Comment: I  got the same value i given in textbox for eg: 20-11-2014

Comment: @shine `20-11-2014` is not a `dd-MMM-yyyy` format.

Comment: @shine did you try to use "/" instead of "-"? And is the txtFromDate is a textField or a variable?

Comment: @shine If I were you, I will use a (SP) Stored Procedure for this, all you have to do is to pass the txtDateFrom value and txtToDate value as a parameter then make the query in the Stored Procedure. Just Easy as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified the incorrect parsing format: `dd-MMM-yyyy`.
Your textboxes are in `dd-MM-yyyy` format.

Change the format, passed to `ParseExact`, and it should work:

```
SqlCommand scmd1 = new SqlCommand("select count(*) Kount  from chequerequests1 where requestdate between '" + DateTime.ParseExact(txtFromDate.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " 00:00:00.000' and '" + DateTime.ParseExact(txtToDate.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " 23:59:59.999' group by chequebookstatus", sc);
```

In general, it is a good idea to stop concatinating strings for building SQL query, and start using SQL parameters.

```
SqlCommand scmd1 = new SqlCommand("select count(*) Kount from chequerequests1 where requestdate between @dateStart and @dateEnd group by chequebookstatus", sc);

DateTime dtStart = DateTime.ParseExact(txtFromDate.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).StartOfDay();
DateTime dtEnd = DateTime.ParseExact(txtToDate.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).EndOfDay();

scmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("dateStart", dtStart);
scmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("dateEnd", dtEnd);
```